# Symmetric DS Bytes threshold

Tags: postgresql, symmetricds

I'm using symmetric ds with postgres and default configuration of symmetric ds.

Always I'm recieving following error.

```
2017-12-20 09:59:53,372 INFO  [SymmetricLauncher] [WrapperSimpleAppMain] Option: name=server, value={}
2017-12-20 09:59:53,390 INFO  [SymmetricLauncher] [WrapperSimpleAppMain] Option: name=port, value={31415}
2017-12-20 09:59:53,577 INFO  [SymmetricWebServer] [WrapperSimpleAppMain] About to start SymmetricDS web server on port 31415
2017-12-20 09:59:57,833 INFO  [DataSourceFactoryBean] [WrapperSimpleAppMain] Setting database connection property application_name=symDS
2017-12-20 09:59:58,491 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [WrapperSimpleAppMain] The DbDialect being used is org.jumpmind.symmetric.db.postgresql.PostgreSqlDbDialect
2017-12-20 09:59:59,546 WARN  [AppUtils] [WrapperSimpleAppMain] Cleaned 2 stranded temporary files.
2017-12-20 09:59:59,554 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [WrapperSimpleAppMain] Initializing SymmetricDS database.
2017-12-20 09:59:59,554 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [WrapperSimpleAppMain] Enabling transaction ID support
2017-12-20 10:00:01,638 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [WrapperSimpleAppMain] Checking if SymmetricDS tables need created or altered.
2017-12-20 10:00:03,272 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [WrapperSimpleAppMain] Done initializing SymmetricDS database.
2017-12-20 10:00:03,530 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [WrapperSimpleAppMain] Starting registered node [group=groupA, id=nodeA, externalId=nodeA]
2017-12-20 10:00:03,542 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [WrapperSimpleAppMain] Synchronizing triggers
2017-12-20 10:00:19,699 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [WrapperSimpleAppMain] Done synchronizing triggers
2017-12-20 10:00:19,700 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [WrapperSimpleAppMain] Updating time and version node info
2017-12-20 10:00:19,812 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [WrapperSimpleAppMain] Updating my node configuration info according to the symmetric properties
2017-12-20 10:00:19,823 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [WrapperSimpleAppMain] Done updating my node info.
2017-12-20 10:00:19,915 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [WrapperSimpleAppMain] Starting job.routing
2017-12-20 10:00:20,041 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [WrapperSimpleAppMain] Starting job.push
2017-12-20 10:00:20,041 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [WrapperSimpleAppMain] Starting job.pull
2017-12-20 10:00:20,042 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [WrapperSimpleAppMain] Starting job.purge.outgoing
2017-12-20 10:00:20,047 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [WrapperSimpleAppMain] Starting job.purge.incoming
2017-12-20 10:00:20,048 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [WrapperSimpleAppMain] Starting job.purge.datagaps
2017-12-20 10:00:20,048 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [WrapperSimpleAppMain] Starting job.stat.flush
2017-12-20 10:00:20,049 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [WrapperSimpleAppMain] Starting job.synctriggers
2017-12-20 10:00:20,049 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [WrapperSimpleAppMain] Starting job.heartbeat
2017-12-20 10:00:20,050 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [WrapperSimpleAppMain] Starting job.watchdog
2017-12-20 10:00:20,050 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [WrapperSimpleAppMain] Started SymmetricDS
2017-12-20 10:00:20,050 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [WrapperSimpleAppMain] SymmetricDS: type=engine, name=SymmetricDS, version=2.5.8, groupId=groupA, externalId=nodeA, databaseName=PostgreSQL, databaseVersion=9.0, driverName=PostgreSQL Native Driver, driverVersion=PostgreSQL 8.4 JDBC4 (build 701)
2017-12-20 10:00:20,454 INFO  [SymmetricWebServer] [WrapperSimpleAppMain] Starting JMX HTTP console on port 31416
2017-12-20 10:00:20,704 INFO  [SymmetricWebServer] [WrapperSimpleAppMain] Joining the web server main thread
2017-12-20 10:00:31,841 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [SymmetricDS-job-9] Routed 6 data events in 3221 ms
2017-12-20 10:00:42,961 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [SymmetricDS-job-6] Routed 4 data events in 1115 ms
2017-12-20 10:01:03,166 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [qtp13676443-17] **Reached byte threshold after 1 batches at 6372163 bytes.  Data will continue to be synchronized on the next pull.**
2017-12-20 10:01:14,077 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [SymmetricDS-job-7] Routed 4 data events in 822 ms
```

I have tried to change **max_data_to_route**, also followed instructions mentioned in https://sourceforge.net/p/symmetricds/discussion/739235/thread/1e2c8469/ 
.

Restarted the symmetric ds after the same, but still having issues.

Regards,
Vishnu G Singhal

Comment: Where's the error?

Comment: NOw I'm facing issue on the error

Answer (score 2):

The "reached byte threshold" log message is not an error -- data is still syncing properly.  It's closing the pull connection early, even though it still has batches to send because it reached the limit on data transfer for the connection.  It will continue on the next pull connection.  You can increase the limit by setting the **transport.max.bytes.to.sync** parameter to a higher value than the default of 1048576 (1MB).  Just make sure your network is reliable enough to handle the data transfer over a single HTTP connection.